# Can a handler method access another handler methods property?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.js. So as my first practice I was creating a todo list.

As you can see in the following code I've defined two handlers for a simple to do app. I have a div which contains one input field and a button to add task...so the addTaskHandler's job is to collect whatever user writes in the input field and upon clicking the ADD button the task will be added to the TASKS array and so on...But it's not working properly.

So if I've defined another handler(pushTaskHandler) for the button which will just add task..and one handler(addTaskHandler) for the input field which will collect the user input and save it ...this way the button handler will access the data from the input handler and add it to the array object list.

So the question is how do I access the data from another handler method?

I tried declaring a variable(newTask) globally and save the input data in there. Later tried to push the data in the Tasks ArrayList. But it is not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Todo/Todo';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    Tasks: [
     {task: "Go to Gym"},
     {task: "Cook Breakfast"},
     {task: "Go to class"},
     {task: "Draw a car and read a book"}
   ]
  }
 }


deleteHandler = (taskIndex)=> {
 const task = [...this.state.Tasks];
 task.splice(taskIndex, 1);
 this.setState({Tasks: task});
}


addTaskHandler = (event) => {
 let newTask = {task: event.target.value};

}

pushTaskHandler = ()=> {
 const task = [...this.state.Tasks];
 task.push(newTask);
 this.setState({Tasks: task});
}



render(){
 let tsk = null;

 tsk = (
  <div>
    {this.state.Tasks.map((t, index)=>{
      return <Task task={t.task}
      deleted={(this.deleteHandler.bind(this, index))}/>
    })}
  </div>
 )
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="add">
      <input type="text"onChange={this.addTaskHandler} placeholder="Add a new task"/>
      <button onClick={this.pushTaskHandler}>ADD</button>
    </div>

   {tsk}
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I expect the data that user types in the input field to be added in the task component upon clicking the ADD button.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a little bit, it can be improved, but you can see how it works. Here we store a task value each time when input changes, and then you can get this value from a state when creating a new task.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    Tasks: [
     {task: "Go to Gym"},
     {task: "Cook Breakfast"},
     {task: "Go to class"},
     {task: "Draw a car and read a book"}
   ]
  }
 }


deleteHandler = (taskIndex)=> {
 const task = [...this.state.Tasks];
 task.splice(taskIndex, 1);
 this.setState({Tasks: task});
}


addTaskHandler = (event) => {
 const inputValue = event.target.value;
 this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    inputValue,
 }));
}

pushTaskHandler = ()=> {
  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    Tasks: [...state.Tasks, { task: state.inputValue}],
    inputValue: ''
  }));
}

render(){
 let tsk = null;

 tsk = (
   <div>
     {this.state.Tasks.map((t, index)=>{
       return <Task task={t.task}
         deleted={(this.deleteHandler.bind(this, index))}/>
     })}
   </div>
 )

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="add">
      <input type="text"onChange={this.addTaskHandler} placeholder="Add a new task"/>
      <button onClick={this.pushTaskHandler}>ADD</button>
    </div>

   {tsk}
  </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: could you please explain how inputValue is stored as an object in the following code         addTaskHandler = (event) => {
 const inputValue = event.target.value;
 this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    inputValue,
 }));
}

Comment: `setState` function can be called with an object as a new state value or updater function, which takes two arguments: `state` and `props`. So in that code, I just copy an existing state and add  `inputValue`. It also can be written as
`this.setState({ ...this.state, inputValue })`. Does it help?